# Difficulties using parent class constructors in subclass

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, extends

I have a `Contractor` subclass that extends of it's parent class `Staff`.

```
    Test Class

    Date macHireDate = new Date(2016, 1, 5);
    Staff mac = new Staff("Mac", 66222222, macHireDate);
    System.out.println(mac);

    Staff bob = new Contractor("Bob", new Date(2012,10,10), new Date(2013,4,11))
    System.out.println(bob);
```

I want the output to be `Bob (ID: None) ...`
But I'm not sure how to make the ID a String. I don't want to change anything in my Test Class

```
public class Contractor extends Staff {
private Date contractEnds;
```

This is my Contractor classes constructor

```
public Contractor(String name, Date hireDate, long employementID, Date contractEnds) {
    super(name, employementID, hireDate);
    this.contractEnds = contractEnds;
}
```

and it's extending off of

```
public Staff(String name, long employementID, Date hireDate) {
super();
this.name = name;
this.hireDate = hireDate;
this.employementID = employementID;
}
```

Bob only has a String, Date, Date. So I'm having difficulties on how to make bobs ID "None" without changing anything in Test Class.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the constructor of `Contractor` to be

```
public Contractor(String name, Date hireDate, Date contractEnds) {
    super(name, 0, hireDate);
    this.contractEnds = contractEnds;
}
```

then also change your `toString` method of `Staff` so that if `employementID` is 0 then it will print `None`

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of a `super()` constructor, and any other additional parameters that need to be initialized, to instantiate the object.

```
public Contractor(String name, Date hireDate, Date contractEnds, int employmentID ) {
    super(name, employmentID, hireDate);
    this.contractEnds = contractEnds;
}
```

The `super()` constructor inherits all of the superclass's constructor code, and initializes all of the corresponding variables in the subclass

you can also write custom code in your methods by adding the `@Override` annotation before it
Example:

```
@Override
public String toString(){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor to Contractor that does not require the ID. Use "this" to call the main constructor with a default ID:

[Warning - untested code ahead]

```
public Contractor(String name, Date hireDate, Date contractEnds) {
    this(name, hireDate, 0, contractEnds);
}
```

You will need to pick some value of type `long` to represent a non-existent ID. I used `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
public class JavaApplication23
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Date macHireDate = new Date(2016, 1, 5);
        Staff mac = new Staff("Mac", 66222222, macHireDate);
        System.out.println(mac);

        Staff bob = new Contractor("Bob", new Date(2012,10,10), 1234L, new Date(2013,4,11));
        System.out.println(bob);

        Staff bob2 = new Contractor("Bob2", new Date(2012,10,10), new Date(2013,4,11));
        System.out.println(bob2);
    }

}

class Contractor extends Staff
{
    private Date contractEnds;

    public Contractor(String name, Date hireDate, long employementID, Date contractEnds)
    {
        super(name, employementID, hireDate);
        this.contractEnds = contractEnds;
    }

    public Contractor(String name, Date hireDate, Date contractEnds)
    {
        super(name, hireDate);
        this.contractEnds = contractEnds;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String out = super.toString();
        return out + "ContractEnds: " + contractEnds + "\n";
    }
}

class Staff
{
    private String name;
    private long employementID;
    private boolean idIsOK;
    private Date hireDate;

    Staff(String name, long employementID, Date hireDate)
    {
        //super();
        this.name = name;
        this.hireDate = hireDate;
        this.employementID = employementID;
        idIsOK = true;
    }

    Staff(String name, Date hireDate)
    {
        //super();
        this.name = name;
        this.hireDate = hireDate;
        this.employementID = -1;
        idIsOK = false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String out = "Name: " + name + "\n";
        out += "HireDate: " + hireDate + "\n";
        out += "EmployementID: " + ((idIsOK) ? employementID : "None") + "\n";
        return out;
    }
}
```

returns:

```
Name: Mac
HireDate: Sat Feb 05 00:00:00 CET 3916
EmployementID: 66222222

Name: Bob
HireDate: Sun Nov 10 00:00:00 CET 3912
EmployementID: 1234
ContractEnds: Sun May 11 00:00:00 CEST 3913

Name: Bob2
HireDate: Sun Nov 10 00:00:00 CET 3912
EmployementID: None
ContractEnds: Sun May 11 00:00:00 CEST 3913
```